# screenshot multiple times program

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I have created a small program that is meant to take a screenshot when I click the button.  It does, however, once I click it and take the screenshot and it saves as "screenshot", I can't click it and take another without overwriting the one I just took.  I want it to be able to take multiple and save them all without closing the program.

[Screenshot of my code that I took with my program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5w4J.png)

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
    package screenshot;

    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\manwe\\Desktop\\java stuff\\6inch_1.png")); // NOI18N
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jButton1)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String format = "png";
        String fileName = "screenshot." + format;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage;
        BufferedImage BufferedImage = screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));


    } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {

    }
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String format = "png";
        String fileName = "screenshot." + format;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage;
        BufferedImage BufferedImage = screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));


    } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {

    }



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Can you put all code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another name for the file. You use the same name, and that is why it overwrites the previous file.

You could append timestamp to the name you have. This would ensure different names for the images.

You can use this code to get the timestamp:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName+timeStamp));
```

Comment: Ok thanks guys for the quick response, this is literally my first project in java, or coding in general.. time to lookup how to append a timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Look at your method `jButton1ActionPerformed(...)`. You are always using the filename `screenshot.png` there. If you don't want to always use the same name, change the code there to use a new, unique name every time you save a screenshot. For example, append a timestamp:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String format = "png";
        String fileName = "screenshot-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + format;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage;
        screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));


    } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! Now if I could just get the program box (the min/max, exit, and java applet symbol) to be a bit smaller, I really just wish I could display as little as possible, just the button, but I guess that's another day and another cup of java.